# GULP - infinity loop while minifying css files

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gulp

I'm new gulp  student and i created some tasks,one of them **minify my css files**, and some **watchers**. One of these watch if the css have changed.

When i  run my program (gulpfile)and make any change into my **sass** file or my **css**, it enters into an  infinity loop and overwrite my minified files over and over

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var cssMin = require('gulp-clean-css');
var min = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

function Default () {

js();

browserSync.init({ 
    server: "./src"
});

gulp.watch('src/sass/*.scss', Sass);
gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change',browserSync.reload);
gulp.watch('src/css/*.css',MinifyCss);

}
function Sass(){

return gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss')
.pipe(sass()) //le decimos que vamos a convertir nuestro archivo sass 
.pipe(gulp.dest("src/css")) //le dcemos que lo guarde aquí
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function MinifyCss(){
  return gulp.src(['src/css/style.css','src/css/bootstrap.css'])
  .pipe(cssMin())
  .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'));
  }


 function js(){
 return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
'node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.js'])
.pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

 function MinifyJs(){
 return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js','node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.js'] 
)
.pipe(min())
.pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('src/js'));
}

exports.default = Default;
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, Alonso. I find a little strange that your scss goes to src/css. then you react and the output goes also to src/css. and then your watch observes the same directory. looks like you need to write somewhere else. Normally you got the src structure and a "dist" or "build" structure where you put the outputs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm....  you're right! it's very odd. but i didn' expected that could cause some troubles